# How do I get faxes to a folder instead of having to print them with an HP printer?

Tags: printer, shared-folders, hp

I've got an **HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M479fdn** which is capable of receiving faxes and save them in a folder. Only when I look at the interface, it tells me I have to enter a "shared folder".

Here is the concerned page:

[image: Fax Setup]

Is there a way to make this work with just standard Linux folders? Or is it necessary for me to setup Samba to get it working? I would prefer to avoid samba if at all possible.

---

### Update:

As answered below, there isn't really another solution. The fact is that I already had samba installed so all I had to do is add one entry like so:

```
[fax]                                                                           
    comment = Faxes on Monster                                                  
    path = /home/fax                                                            
    read only = no                                                              
    browsable = yes
```

create the user:

```
sudo adduser --system --ingroup sambashare fax
sudo mkdir /home/fax/folder
sudo chown fax:sambashare /home/fax/folder
sudo passwd fax
```

and restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart smbd
```

Then I could use the following share folder in my HP settings:

```
\\fax\folder
```

which was accepted. The next page asks for the user and password, I used "fax" and the password I entered when I ran `passwd`.

I'm not 100% sure that it works at this point, I need to receive a fax...

Part of this setup is based on the Ubuntu [install and configure samba](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look into the german and english manual and I couldn't find the setting for saving faxes to network folders.

But I saw how you configure it for scanning. They describe how to configure Windows to share a folder. I don't think, they reinvented the wheel for the fax functionality, so I suggest you to use SMB.

Answer (score 1):

How about NAS?

In a similar (I think) case, I just spend a two hundred dollars on a NAS hardware and HDD for it.

The NAS provides different network protocols, so my Linux machines goes to it by NFS, Windows through a standard SMB (which is done by samba on Linux). Mac guests also have access somehow (I just tell them IP address of the NAS).

Comment: Well, I was hoping to not have to add any more hardware... and if I have to anyway install Samba on my Linux box, the results would be the same, right?

Comment: No, I do not have samba on my Linux boxes, just nfs.